# i want rows with different category id using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i passed employee id and category id to this function.
this employee posted some requirements for some users under severval category. and employees posted for same users with same category multiple times.so i want that repeated ones as single record.anybody knows,please help

```
     public function get_data_print($id,$cat_id) {

              $this->db->from('jil_requirementbrief');
                $this->db->where('jil_requirementbrief.rqm_managedby', $id);
                  $this->db->where('jil_requirementbrief.rqm_category', $cat_id);

                $query = $this->db->get();
$this->db->from('jil_users'); 
       $this->db->where('jil_users.usr_id',$row->rqm_customerid);
          $query2= $this->db->get()->row_object();
          $row->users_name = $query2->usr_name;
           $row->users_comp = $query2->usr_company;
}
```

Comment: Hello @user6021279 would please explain your problem more specifically such as we can help you in proper way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use group_by to avoid duplication

```
$this->db->group_by('column_name');
```

Or you can try distict

```
$this->db->distinct();
```